# Easy Labels do not show when opening project on another machine

Tags: qgis

Love the easy label plugin, once I got the hang of it. I opened the project file on my desktop after setting up all the labels on my laptop and they do not show. I assume they will once I open the Project on my laptop again.

Thoughts?

Comment: Sorry, what's the question? It seems to be easy to try out yourself ...

Comment: You would think. I didn't have the laptop with me and I wanted to work on a project last night. I did not save the project on the Desktop and reopened it this morning on the laptop and the labels are not there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use also Memory Layer saver plugin (v2.1) to save those labeling layers. 
There are some save / restore issues with 2.0 and 0.9 version of that plugin. 2.1 is fine. 
If you find any bug, please use hub.qgis.org/projects/easycustomlabeling/issues
regards
régis